# Using Composer to Migrate Data from GCS to BigQuery

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am writing a script to merge 500 files in my gcs bucket and move the merged file to BigQuery. I am using composer to run the script. I created the dag, but I am getting the following error. I do not know what the error means.

**[2024-02-19, 22:24:46 UTC] {subprocess.py:97} INFO - Command exited with return code -9
[2024-02-19, 22:24:50 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1853} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash.py", line 196, in execute
raise AirflowException(
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed. The command returned a non-zero exit code -9.**

```
load_to_bq_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='load_to_bq_task',
    bash_command ='gsutil cp gs://merge-file-code/load_to_bq.py /tmp && python /tmp/load_to_bq.py',
    dag=dag,
)

Any suggestions are welcome
```

Comment: There's an Operator to do that: [GCSToBigQueryOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/gcs_to_bigquery/index.html).